# slide on libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm doing the shop screen. Shop has 3 pages. And I wrote the slide code. It works fine on PC but it does not work well on Android.

Video: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3a1uaaj20urxm8j/V_20170619_171001.mp4?dl=0)

Game is here: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arinso.endurn)

Codes here (UPDATED):

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
     if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
                touchPX = Gdx.input.getX();
     }
    HOR  += (touchPX - Gdx.input.getX());
    touchPX = Gdx.input.getX();
} 

SB.draw(pokeball, -HOR + 123,123);
```

Where is the problem and how can i solve ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Maybe you can solve this problem

Comment: I tested your app but not able to get what's the problem, In you linked video it appears that somehow you're not able to slide your shop page.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan For better understanding of the problem, I removed the page stabilizer on video. Does it work completely fine on your device ? If so, why is there a problem with me? I tested on my tablet and phone. I send a message to your facebook address about codes. I haven't solved this problem for a long time. I'll be very happy if you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with `Gdx.input.getDeltaX()`:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){ 
    HOR -= Gdx.input.getDeltaX();
} 

SB.draw(pokeball, -HOR + 123,123);
```

`Gdx.input.GetDeltaX()` gives the x change so i wasn't need extra codes.